# Cloth simulated object particles don't simulate when start and end emission frames are different

Tags: particles, physics, cloth-simulation

I have a pretty weird problem with particle systems in blender, been looking for an answer for about 10 hours now. Here's the deal:
I'm trying to model some money effect.
I created a plane with texture and physics (cloth) applied to it, and a separate particle system. But when I try to apply a particle instance to my plane for the particle systems, **the physics** (that were working perfectly with my plane) **now don't work**. My particles keep bouncing when falling on the collision plane beneath.
It only seems to work when  I set the start and the end of the emission to 1. When I try to set different values (e.g. start:1, end:50), my physics is gone.
It may be that I'm missing something here, but I truly can't find an answer.
Thanks for each helpful answer.

Comment: Try increasing the particle damping settings on the collision object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
I've tried it and it doesn't help unfortunately.
However the simulation is fine as long as the particles are rendered at once (emission start and end is set to 1).
The problem occurs only when it should render the particles longer than 1 frame.

Comment: That's odd.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Sure thing. I just made a simplified version, with only the money model, the emitter and the plane under them.
I uploaded the blend file to my webpage (don't know a way to upload it here).
Here's the link: http://varykeramia.hu/blender/bounce.blend

Comment: Turning the particle damping of the green plane from 0 to something realistic solves it for me. Are you sure you tried setting the damping in the collison options of the green plane? Bouncing can also be introduced by cache step settings, but yours seem ok. Make sure to start the animation from frame 1 after you changed settings.

Comment: Thanks man, I tried it, and its a bit better now, but the original problem is that the physics of the **money model** doesn't take effect. If you have some more time, please try playing the simulation this way:
select the _emitter_, in the _Particle_ tab under _emission_ set both the start and the end to **1**.
This way the physics of the money model _does_ take effect.
If you set for the start and end different frames, the money model's physics doesnt take effect.
And I plan to add some wind effect in the future too, which will look pretty weird without realistc physics.